# How do I upload files to pocketbase?

Tags: javascript, file, svelte, pocketbase

I am using pocketbase and svelte.js.
How can I upload pictures to pocketbase via an html input.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { currentUser, pb } from './pocketbase';
    const axios = require('axios').default;

    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

    async function uploadFile() {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/collections/images/records',
            data: {
                image: fileInput.file,
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" on:submit={uploadFile}>
    <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're querying an element that does not exist yet.
You should not querying it anyway but binding it to a svelte variable.
Also you shouldn't use CJS require client side with svelte.
Also, you don't need axios, especially if you're using sveltekit which has an isomorphic  fetch version.

Comment: Take a look here: https://pocketbase.io/docs/files-handling/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance instead of JSON.

Here's an example:

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('image', image); // here the image is appended to the form data

await pb.collection('posts').create(formData) // replace 'posts' with your collection
```

> Once added, you could create/update a Record and upload "documents" files by sending a `multipart/form-data` request using the Records create/update APIs.
>
> [From the pocketbase docs](https://pocketbase.io/docs/files-handling/)

Comment: Can you show the format in which the image should be sent?

Comment: I am following this steps and I get an error saying the image is on the wrong format, I am taking the image from the value of an input type file